# Where do I import Spark DayTimeIntervalType data type from?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In every spark/pyspark reference I see DayTimeIntervalType and YearMonthIntervalType data types but these are neither in package pyspark.sql.types (pyspark) nor org.apache.spark.sql.types._ (scala). There is no example using them with import statements included I could find. Please enlighten me where I suppose to import them from.
Thanks

Comment: What is you Spark version? This is added in Spark version 3.2.x. It is in the package org.apache.spark.sql.types only. You can find it here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DayTimeIntervalType.html

Comment: Source https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DayTimeIntervalType.scala

Comment: I have the same problem in the community databricks cluster, spark version 3.2.1. Unfortunately pyspark contains it from 3.3: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/python/pyspark/sql/types.py